# Move app to sdcard drama

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sdcard

So I want the users to be able to move an app to an sdcard if they own one. I used to have these permissions since 2013 but I removed them:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    ...
</manifest>
```

because they would warn the user on Google Play that the app had access to Media/photos etc, which was a bit invasive.

So now the app doesn't have any permissions. Can the users move the app without any permissions to an sdcard? And if they can't, what permissions should I use?

Comment: What is it that you cant answer this yourself? Why didnt you try? A little test will do.

Comment: Yeah I know I could test it but I dont have an sdcard or a phone that accepts sdcard, so yeah.

Comment: You will not need those permissions as your app is not writing if it's moved. The OS needs write permission if it moves your app. I think the OS has it ;-).

Answer (score 0):

if your'e targettingSdk is above 23 you should take danger permission called runtime permissions